# Design View option disabled when right-clicking objects in navigation pane

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

When I right-click an object in the Navigation Pane (Access 2010) the Design View option is disabled (greyed-out).

I have tested this on multiple objects (forms, tables, and queries) in multiple database (both mdb and accdb) with the same results. I have had other users test this (using the same databases and objects I tested with) and nobody else is having this problem. I tried rebooting. I compared my Access options to other users and they were identical.

Fortunately, I am able to open objects by double-clicking them, then I can change the view from the ribbon. However, in cases where the object is an executable query (i.e. queries that delete, update, append, or make a table), I have no way to enter design view. Additionally, if there is an error preventing an object from being opened normally (i.e. in datasheet/form view) then I have no way of fixing it in design view!

At this point I'm considering reinstalling Access. Looking for alternative suggestions here. Please help!

Comment: Have you added any code to create or customize your in-built menus. That will change the behavior of all menus within Access.

Comment: Corporate is making us add a new security module to the vba in all our Access databases soon and I had to test it. It's possible that did something. I'll take a look. Do you know how this would be done in vba? There is a lot of code, just want to know what to look for...

Comment: Open Access while holding down the shift key. That should bypass whatever you blocked.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a previous comment, I had been testing a new security module provided by IT. I confirmed this module caused the problem by testing it on a different machine. I informed IT and they were able to provide a sub routine to undo the issue.